# Android Espresso Assertion Issue

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to assert a text is NOT in the view.

```
//ViewInteraction appCompatTextView10 = onView(
                allOf(withText("Politics"), not(isDisplayed())));
        appCompatTextView10.perform(click());//
```

is not working.

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.title), not(withText("Politics"))));
```

is not working either.

any help ? is doesnotexists() deprecated ? I am not able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
onView(withText("Politics")).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

if the view does not exist in the view hierarchy use this instead:

```
onView(withText("Politics")).check(doesNotExist());
```